# is it possible to create an automatic getter method for public field

Tags: java

I have field in my class

```
public int author;
```

this field contains uniq id of and user stored in my database. for some reasons I can't set here an object of user just the value of his id and also the field needs to be public. Now I would like to creat auto getter for this field that is return and object. So when I do `object.author` I'll receive object of User not integer. I think that is not possible but I want to check :)

Comment: Are you using an ORM framework like Hibernate?

Comment: Doing a getter for a public field has no many sense

Comment: Imagine that some evil programmer tampers with your code and he does something like this: `object.author = 0; session.flush();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way you want a custom autoboxing feature where author changes to user object.

```
 User u = object.author;
```

Java doesn't provides custom autoboxing.
So what you are asking is not possible.

Another way of saying same thing is you want to overload `=` operator but java doesn't provide that option. So again not possible and here is the reason for this : http://www.cafeaulait.org/javafaq.html#xtocid1902938